# CSS animation doesn't work in Firefox and JSFiddle

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I have strange problem - this code doesn't fade in tooltip in Firefox.

Here is my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/2VsTp/11/

**CSS**

```
@-webkit-keyframes showTooltip {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

@-moz-keyframes showTooltip {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes showTooltip {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

.form-item {position: relative;}

.message-error:after {
    content: attr(data-tooltip);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 10%;
    display: none;
    padding: 1em 2em;
    color: white;
    -webkit-animation: showTooltip 0.35s ease-in-out; 
    -moz-animation: showTooltip 0.35s ease-in-out;
    animation: showTooltip 0.35s ease-in-out;
}

.message-error:hover:after {
    display: block;
}

.message-error:after {background-color: red;}
```

Thank You for hints in advance!

Comment: You say it doesn't work on jsFiddle, but what if you run the stylesheet through the SASS preprocessor first?

Comment: Ok, now is better in Chrome in jsFiddle (wonder why) but still - there is no animation in Firefox :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the animation from **.message-error:after** to **.message-error:hover:after**

```
.message-error:hover:after {
    display: block;
     -webkit-animation: showTooltip 0.35s ease-in-out; 
    -moz-animation: showTooltip 0.35s ease-in-out;
    animation: showTooltip 0.35s ease-in-out;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rooseve/2VsTp/14/

But I'm not sure why **message-error:after** works for Chrome.

Comment: Yes... in Firefox, the animation apparently runs when the page is loaded and the after block is still invisible. At least I think that's what happens. Not sure what the official word is on this behaviour. Maybe Chrome does it right and Firefox is wrong! Anyway, I think the OP is better off with a transition rather than an animation.

Comment: I would use transition, but it works only with opacity 0/1 instead display: none/block - that's why I've used animation...